# Can i hyperlink to a page in my files?

Tags: python, html

I want to hyperlink to a page in my local files, i thought you could just do this by doing this;

```html
<a target="_blank" href="http://unity3d.com">
  <input type="image" id="Unity3d" position:absolute style="height:100px; width:150px;" src="./Images/UnityButton.PNG">
</a>
```

as you can see i have embedded it inside of a button which is a image...This doesnt work, **so what im asking is how do i hyperlink my button to a local file.**

- filename : Python.html
- Where is it: C:\Users\ashsa_000\Desktop\Html\Revision.HTML

Comment: You should be able to use a relative path. This will not display the image if server from a remote host. Otherwise, please check of provide the file structure including the location of the script being run and the image itself. The path is often case sensitive, so double check that as well. My guess is the image is not in that path relative to where the script is _run_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

link to something like:

```
file:///Users/ashsa_000/Desktop/Html/Revision.HTML
```

Comment: Thanks, i have got a feeling that it does work however its saying the page is not found. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

`src="Images/UnityButton.png"` should work for an image located in an "Images" directory in the same directory as Python.html